нужно создать список из элементов целого числа на c++
у меня есть int значение из которого нужно получить список на c++, где будет каждый элемент intа(если список будет инвертирован, то это даже лучше). Вот пример такого кода на python:
arr_a = []
a = int(input())
a1 = a
len_a = len(str(a))

for i in range(len_a):
    arr_a.append(a1 % 10)
    a1 = a1 // 10

print(arr_a) 


А что именно вы не знаете, как сделать в C++? Со строкой работать ни к чему, используйте цикл do..while(a)

Кроме того, в C++ вам, вероятно, лучше будет использовать вектор, а не список

Вообще-то понятие "элемент числа" — это как-то...  А код — так можно просто дословно перевести питоновый :) Но, конечно, в каждой избушке свои игрушки, каждый язык со своими идиомами.

Видимо "элемент числа" здесь - это цифра десятичного разряда. Тогда проще читать из ввода по одному символу, а не гонять его в int и обратно раскладывать.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int a;
    std::cout << "число: ";
    std::cin >> a;

    std::vector<int> arr_a;
    
    while (a > 0) {
        arr_a.push_back(a % 10);
        a = a / 10;
    }

    std::cout << "цифры в инвертированном порядке: ";
    for (int digit : arr_a) {
        std::cout << digit << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

